# Is there a difference between length of a decimal?

Tags: sql

I have a column that has decimal lengths of 11 total digits (0.4335687532, -0.4216776567), however, I created the datatype in SQL as decimal(18,15), which ultimately adds five `0`s at the end of the decimal. The reason I did this was because new data could have more digits, but there is no indication that it will. I am wondering if adding these decimals will ultimately impact any performance or anything else I might be missing.

Comment: You should tell us which database you are using, which could influence the answer.  Obviously, it might have a storage penalty, if those significant figures are taking up extra space.

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *precision* determines the length of the decimal value, not the *scale*.  So, `decimal(18, 5)` and `decimal(18, 15)` typically occupy the same number of bytes on a data page.

The amount added no doubt depends on the database you are using -- each database is free to store decimals in its own format.  But typically, the format would use one byte for every two decimal places and maybe another byte or two of overhead.  So, the extra 5 zeros would typically require 2-3 more bytes of storage.

Such overhead is usually pretty minor when determining the behavior of a database.  After all, the unit of reading and writing data is measured in data pages -- and these are usually measured in kilobytes to megabytes.

Depending on the system (hardware and software), arithmetic operations on slightly longer numerics might take slightly more time.

Overall, though, it is hard to think of a scenario where performance would be noticeably affected.